# Escaping urls in CSS

Tags: css, moodle

I'm designing a page in moodle (arrg), and I need to escape the url so moodle wouldn't recognise it as a url.
My code:

```
<td style="background-image: url('http://example.com/pluginfile.php/788/mod_forum/intro/header_start.jpg');>
```

Moodle recognised the "link" and so wraps it with an `<a>` tag

```
<td style="background-image: url('&lt;a href=" http:="" example.com="" pluginfile.php="" 788="" mod_forum="" intro="" header_start.jpg'"="" class="_blanktarget">http://example.com/pluginfile.php/788/mod_forum/intro/header_start.jpg'); width: 55px; height: 50px;"&gt;
```

Could you think of any possible way to get around this? I thought maybe something like:

```
url('ht'+'tp://example.com/pluginfile.php/788/mod_forum/intro/header_start.jpg');
```

But I couldn't find anything about url concatenation in css.

Comment: Are your images on the same domain name ? If yes you can avoid the http://www.example.com part... but i suppose it's a no ? :)

Comment: @PierreGranger - I would venture to guess that the autolinking feature checks for relative URLs as well. It just doesn't know to skip them if they are inside an attribute.

Comment: Pierre, I'm afraid @Anthony is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Autolinking), you should be able to disable the auto-linking feature but wrapping the section where it shouldn't occur with  ... , so in your case:

```
<nolink>
<td  style="background-image: url('http://example.com/blah.jpg');">
</nolink>
```

Or, you could just add a style block above the relevant code and uses classes or ids, assuming that moodle knows to skip over those elements.

Also, try changing your markup to:

```
<td  style="background-image: url(http://example.com/blah.jpg);">
```

it's possible that the single quotes inside the double quotes is throwing off any "skip checking attributes" type filter.  And your example code doesn't have the `style` attribute close quotes, in case that's not a typo.